# Get info from offline server with node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I have a full stack project, UI using React Native, backend with node.js

the app is currency exchange.

is there a way to get info from the server when even if its offline?
i read about webSocket but not sure if its the solution.

another solution I will try (not the best one) is to keep some of the data in local storage,
so if the server is offline I will display the currency exchange by the last time the user did the exchange.

Thank for the help.